# Private bridges in Kubernetes

Tags: networking, kubernetes, antrea, ovs, multus

I have a Docker-based working project that I'd like to migrate to Kubernetes.  The Docker version of the project is a mini-range for a class of about 35 students.  It's Docker-based and uses OpenVirtualSwitch (OVS) to provide each student with the same (but separate) target architecture.  It looks something like:

`Student01 = Kali-01 (192.168.10.1) -> br-01 -> Target-01 (192.168.10.2)`
`Student02 = Kali-02 (192.168.10.1) -> br-02 -> Target-02 (192.168.10.2)`
`Student03 = Kali-03 (192.168.10.1) -> br-03 -> Target-03 (192.168.10.2)`

and so on (with a Guacamole front-end).  Because the bridge for each architecture only connects to the two containers, it's effectively a private bridge for each set of containers, allowing re-use of the same IP addresses in each student's environment.

I'm finding out (the hard way) that Kubernetes' network model doesn't support this (using Multus with Flannel or Cilium).  My question is: would switching the CNI to Antrea, OVS-CNI, or something else provide Kubernetes with the capability to have multiple, private bridges with the same IP space?